# How to show the image in vf page from the formula field

Tags: visualforce, formula-field

I have upload the image in document and I would like to insert the uploaded image in formula field using the apex code.

I would like to achieve store the image for every record.
Need to show the VF page.

Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "insert the uploaded image in formula field using the apex code."  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create the richtextfield and insert the image like below.

```
map.put(RichtextFiledname, '<img src=" url" />');
insert map;
```